# Who to print this query result which is greater than 0

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?= number_format((isset($prdRow->SaleVal))?($prdRow->SaleVal / (30) * ($Logdays) 
    - ((isset ($disp10->dispamount10))?$disp10->dispamount10 - ((isset($disp1->dispamount1))?$disp1->dispamount1:0) :0) 
     - ((isset($disp2->SumOfCash))?$disp2->SumOfCash:0)
      - ((isset($prdRow->ClosingVal))?$prdRow->ClosingVal-($ret_unitsAmt):0))* ((100- $CustDiscount)/100)   
    :0,0)?>
```

Comment: Please explain what the exact problem do you have, do not just copy and paste your code here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through the help center, in particular How do I ask a good question?

Comment: Are you looking for `echo` or `print_r()` ?

Comment: actually this query working fine now i  want to add one more  condition that just print value which is greater than 0 

<td width="76"><?= number_format((isset($prdRow->SaleVal))?($prdRow->SaleVal / (30) * ($Logdays) 
 - ((isset ($disp10->dispamount10))?$disp10->dispamount10 - ((isset($disp1->dispamount1))?$disp1->dispamount1:0) :0) 
  - ((isset($disp2->SumOfCash))?$disp2->SumOfCash:0)
   - ((isset($prdRow->ClosingVal))?$prdRow->ClosingVal-($ret_unitsAmt):0))* ((100- $CustDiscount)/100) 
 :0,0)?>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your guestion properly (which was really hard by the way) what you looking for is:

```
<?php
$numberToDisplay = number_format((isset($prdRow->SaleVal))?($prdRow->SaleVal / (30) * ($Logdays) 
- ((isset ($disp10->dispamount10))?$disp10->dispamount10 - ((isset($disp1->dispamount1))?$disp1->dispamount1:0) :0) 
 - ((isset($disp2->SumOfCash))?$disp2->SumOfCash:0)
  - ((isset($prdRow->ClosingVal))?$prdRow->ClosingVal-($ret_unitsAmt):0))* ((100- $CustDiscount)/100)   
:0,0);

if ($numberToDisplay > 0) {
  echo $numberToDisplay;
}
?>
```